# Can't read a character from the keyboard using Eclipse on Mac Yosemite

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, input

Is something broken in Eclipse/Yosemite? I've tried everything I can think of to read a typed key and it's always ignored and the program terminates with no message and goes back to the editor.

Current attempt is this:

```
System.out.println( "Read the keyboard");

        try {
            selection = (char) System.in.read();
            System.out.print("You entered ");
            System.out.println(selection);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error reading from user: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println( "Selection: " + selection);
```

"Read the keyboard" is output to the Eclipse console, then the program goes back to the editor. I've tried other methods of reading the keyboard, all with the same result.

Comment: Are you focused on the Console window when trying to input?

Comment: Oh, crap, I didn't know I had to be! Seems to work if I do that. Please forgive stupidity.